# Session Handling in WCF with a Java Client

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security

What's the best way to implement Session Handling in a WCF Service if the client that is using the service is not a WCF client but a Java client ?
Is it possible to use the integrated Service model?

Thank you!
Dominik

Answer (score 0):

The session is controller by the WCF service and how it is configured.  Set to an instance more of PerSession, that WCF object will last as long as the client proxy is in use and all calls on that proxy will be serviced by that object.